# Simple Update error

Tags: sql

I am trying the following simple SQL to update the column for each row
where the last two conditions (both dates) are equal. No rows are affected though.

If I omit the `where` clause it updates with the same column value.

```
UPDATE VyfjaarOntledings
SET LaasteSuiker = Suiker
WHERE LaasteMonsterDatum = Datum
```

Any ideas ?

Regards

Comment: please add tag which RDBMS you are using

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a tag DBMS , assuming that you are using SQL Server..

Convert the comparisons column to make sure it has the same datatype to avoid errors.

**CONVERT**

```
UPDATE VyfjaarOntledings
SET LaasteSuiker = Suiker
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, LaasteMonsterDatum) = CONVERT(DATE, Datum)
```

**CAST**

```
UPDATE VyfjaarOntledings
SET LaasteSuiker = Suiker
WHERE CAST(LaasteMonsterDatum AS DATE) = CAST(Datum AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thank you.I have changed the code to convert the date columns, but still no results. I want to use the date in the LaastemonsterDatum to find the suiker in a row with the same date in the datum column as the Laastemonsterdatum. I am using SQL server by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess time part is different in `LaasteMonsterDatum` and `Datum` column.

Try removing the time part from date and update

```
UPDATE VyfjaarOntledings
SET LaasteSuiker = Suiker
WHERE cast(LaasteMonsterDatum as date) = cast(Datum as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Format of date column could be problem. For safety always use Cast or TO_Date functions for comparing dates